# Power golden rails from minecart(placing rails in large scale)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Is there any way how to power golden rails from within minecart? What I mean is placing rails on the go and also some way of powering them immediately.

To place them on the go is easy, I just put a minecart with a furnace behind me and hold "use" button for placing them, but if I place the golden ones, they're deactivated, so they slow me down.

The only thing I can think of are detectors, but those are pretty much useless here, because:

- the time the golden rails stay active is the same as if I'd use a button
- switching between items even with numbers on keyboard is slow

When I played minecraft PE, there it was directly placing powered rails(redstone didn't work). Isn't in PC version something similar? Or maybe some way for placing two items at the same time?

Comment: Your PE version is out dated

Comment: @Fennekin `when I played` doesn't mean I play it anymore or... that I update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple.
First get all the rails. Let the powered rails be aside.

First place all the rails in the line( assuming you are traveling straight). Place them from start to end. And use engine (furnace minecart).

Now next at stations place 3 powered rails successively next to each other and have a button to power them.

Now the part to place and power powered rails:

Once you ride off from the 3 powered rail i.e. the station you will travel approximately 70 to 80 blocks before loosing momentum. So the trick is to place 3 successive powered rails every 80 blocks. Power them with lever on side of block. Continue this until the end. It will take quite while but it is worth doing it.

I had done this back in 1.7.2 in a survival world. (yes survival and the length was 1000 rails exactly to get the achievement and it took 2 days to mine 396 iron if I remember correctly and 1 day to place all the blocks in a straight line. however when I updated the game to 1.8 all achievements kept on resetting)

[see this you will get idea how the rails were placed. I placed powered rail when I felt the momentum of mine cart was low](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEL11.jpg)

Comment: Powering "powered rails" by lever will not take any redstone. Comparing your detector rail idea

Comment: Something faster would be better in a large scale, but I still like it though! Also, the momentum - around 60-70 it's maximum I think if you of course don't want to move yourself. Note that if you plan to go up, you'd need to use a shorter distance. Maybe if this process could be implemented as a command block(at least for traveling straight), it'd be less painful for long distances. I don't know if it's possible, though :)